# How to do on Button click animation Like in Google android application back Button?

Tags: android, animation, button, material-design

I need to know How to recreate the button animation Like the Open Navigation Drawer and back buttons on **Google Apps**,

Open NavMenu button `rotates 360` then changes to back button in the tool bar with the fading in or out responding fragments, then if you pressed back button the same animation sequence occur reversely

You can observe it if you opened your Gmail

Comment: u need navigation drawer animation or a simple button animation.?

Comment: button animation as what is in the google apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Maybe this library will help you. 
A library to bring fully animated Material Design components to pre-Lolipop Android.*

Check [github sample](https://github.com/rey5137/material).

*or if you are looking navigation drawer samples like in google apps,
please check this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) .*